# BrowserSync command line Cannot GET /

Tags: html, npm, browser-sync, npm-scripts

I'm trying to create a simple Browser Sync server for just HTML and CSS.

Following the examples at [Browser Sync documentation](https://browsersync.io/docs/command-line) I have this package.json with the start script:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "browser-sync start --server 'src' --files 'src'"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "",
  "devDependencies": {
    "browser-sync": "^2.23.6"
  }
}
```

My folders structure is:

```
node_modules
src
└───index.html
package.json
```

However, when I execute `npm start` the browser opens at `http://localhost:3000/` but it just displays **Cannot GET /**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `start` script in `package.json` to the following:

```json
...
"scripts": {
  "start": "browser-sync start --server \"src\" --files \"src/**\"",
},
...
```

**Notes**

1. The path arguments for both `--server` and `--files` have been wrapped in escaped double quotes. (i.e. `\"...\"`) as Windows doesn't recognize single quotes (i.e. `'...'`)
2. The `--files` argument has been changed from `'src'` to `\"src/**\"` - it now includes the `/**` glob pattern.

Comment: This helped me, I had the same problem. It was the use of single quotes that was the problem. the /** glob pattern isn't necessary.